# Untar on Windows: tar.exe: Error opening archive: gzip decompression failed

Tags: r

```
download.file("https://www.dropbox.com/s/k9ptc4kep9hmvz5/1kg_phase1_all.tar.gz?raw=1",
              destfile = "tmp-data/1kg_phase1_all.tar.gz")
untar("tmp-data/1kg_phase1_all.tar.gz", exdir = "tmp-data")
```

This works on Linux, but give the following error on Windows: `tar.exe: Error opening archive: gzip decompression failed`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you need to use `mode = "wb"` in `download.file()`.